# TextView gravity not working with Hebrew

Tags: android, textview, hebrew, gravity

I have TextView on Hebrew that i want to be on the right side, so i'm doing

```
<TextView....
    android:gravity="right"
</TextView>
```

On some phones it will be aligned to right and on some it will be aligned to left.
I think it depends on some phone configuration.
How i can fix it ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This might be an issue. If it's not in the Android's [issue page](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) consider reporting it.

For now you can try fixing it placing the `TextView` inside a `ViewGroup`.
Use `wrap_content` and `layout_gravity` to place it correctly inside it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

Android currently doesn't support BiDi text.  Some manufacturers have hacked it in, but until this is a standard part of the platform you can expect any use of BiDi text to result in inconsistent, broken behavior.  Sorry.

Comment: Is there a flag to tell if a certain manufacture has hacked this in?

Answer (score 1):

`Android: Gravity` might not work properly in case `android:layout_height` or `android:layout_weight` is set to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. If your text is in hebrew, you don't need to set gravity, because it would be aligned without it. I came to this when I saw latin symbols in my views, which were on the right. Though, there is still bug in SDK layout editor.

**Tested on LG GT540 and Samsung Galaxy S**

Answer (score 0):

if you wish the text to be aligned to the right , try using this:

```
textView.setText("\u200F"+content);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the older android versions don't support rtl too well.
For me what worked eventually was a webview.
Because then I just used CSS to design my text.
You will also need an onTouchListener if you want it to do something when clicked

change your TextView to Webview:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/noticetit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

My code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.noticetit);
private void setWebView() {
            String htmlcss = "<html lang=\"he\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" />"
                    + "<style type=\"text/css\">.rtl {direction: rtl;color:black;font:20px arial;}</style></head>"
                    + "<body class=\"rtl\"><div class=\"rtl\">" + webView
                    + "</div></body></html>";

            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlcss, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                // Removed @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.maintitle
                            && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        //Put your code here
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Comment: This is _not_ what OP is looking for. `android:layout_gravity` suggests where a view should be placed within its parent. `android:gravity` is supposed to control how a TextView aligns its text when the text is narrower or shorter than the view.